# How to create a service with WMIC?

Tags: services, wmic

I wrote a service program with `WinAPI` functions with `c++` And I want to create that by `wmic.exe` in service manager with bellow `command` :

```
service create name="test" where path = "C:\Users\msi\Desktop\SampleService.exe"
```

But it give me the `error` :

> ```
> Invalid format.
> Hint: <assignlist> = <propertyname>=<propertyvalue> [, <assignlist>].
> ```

How can i create a service with `wmic.exe` tool?

Comment: why not use sc.exe from normal commandline? is wmic requirement?

Comment: @Drako I know `sc.exe` but i have to use of `wmic`.

Comment: The error message means that you shouldn't use `where` and should write it like `service create name="test", path="xxx"` but this doesn't work either. As far as I can see, `wmic` cannot create a system service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer is that `wmic` cannot create a new system service.

I have run an elevated Command Prompt and executed the command
`wmic service create /?:Full`, to receive this output:

[image]

The list of properties has included every possible argument that a system
service would require, all marked as "N/A", meaning "Not Applicable".

I have also searched on google for `"wmic service create"`, and found a paltry
four answers, but none of them was related to creating a service.

I think that you will need to resort to another tool than `wmic`.

For example, PowerShell documentation includes the applet
[New-Service](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-service?view=powershell-6).

WMI itself includes such a method in
[Create method of the Win32_Service class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/create-method-in-class-win32-service),
but you will need to call it via other method than `wmic`.

Comment: Thanks. but what is the application of `create` in wmic for `service` ?

Comment: `create` is a legal keyword and works for other verbs like `process` but not for `service`. Seems like this combination of keywords was just never implemented, by intention or by omission, so it only generates a non-informative error message. When I try it with a correct syntax, I get the message "ERROR:
Description = Unsupported parameter", which I think means that "service create" is unsupported.